# Pip freeze gives me this error related with git

Tags: python, git, heroku, turbogears, turbogears2

I am working with python and git on a simple Turbogears2 project that I've built just for fun. In a certain moment I want to deploy it to Heroku, so I do the usual `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and I get this error:

```
Error when trying to get requirement for VCS system Command /usr/bin/git config
remote.origin.url failed with error code 1 in /home/ricardo/myprojs/hellotg22/example,
falling back to uneditable format
```

And in the `requirements.txt` that it produces, listed between all the dependencies, I find this line, whi doesn't look good at all:

```
...
decorator==3.4.0
## !! Could not determine repository location
example==0.1dev
...
```

Does any body know what the problem is?

Anyway, I have managed to obtain the requirements.txt file, but I would like to know what is going on with that error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your git repository doesn't have an "origin" so pip is unable to detect the remote url of the repository. This should have been already fixed in PIP as stated in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/58

Try to upgrade pip or add a remote origin to your git repository

Comment: Hi. I have updated pip with `sudo pip install --upgrade distribute` within its virtual environment, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: But adding the remote, seems to have solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I had this same error but even with my remote origin there, it still produces the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error while working in an editable install (`pip install -e .`) of my project. So I added a localhost remote (`git remote add origin git@localhost:the_project_name`) and now `pip freeze` doesn't complain anymore. I got the idea from https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-locally/

Comment: Adding an `origin` clearly resolves it. The idea of this dummy `origin` is really neat though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip freeze -l` since it also works within a virtual environment. So your command would then be `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt`. I use this and it works just fine.

According to the help menu:

```
Freeze Options:
  -l, --local                 If in a virtualenv that has global access, do not output globally-
                              installed packages.
```

Comment: I see that you had the same issue on Github. Did this solution actually work for you? (Same results for me.)